# Should I use Cloud Functions to verify recaptcha secret of an Angular 7.x form using ng-recaptcha?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, recaptcha

I've written a form using a recent version of angular, I were able to write the forms to the Firebase database when the rules were set to read/write by anyone. After ensuring this worked, I changed the rules. My next task was to configure recaptcha, so I added ng-recaptcha from npm, which renders fine. This step involved exposing the client-side key. However, I haven't been able to understand how to properly validate the recaptcha results.

It renders fine on all browsers and after answering it, I get a token-like string. It is my understanding that this response then needs to be validated against the recaptcha api.

I also understand that this step would need my secret key. And that I wouldn't put this secret key anywhere on the client-code.

Therefore, I presume that my next step would involve setting up a server/rest api in order to securely validate the response from the user, with my secret key against Google's api. So, would a Firebase Cloud Function be a good way to achieve this objective?

I am not understanding from the ng-recaptcha documentation if there is an alternative way to validate the human response securely.

Lastly, since my subsequent step is to securely write to the firebase database the validated entries from the form, would this all be achieved also from a cloud function in a single step? I've been unable to write to the database using credentials once is locked for authorized access and need to learn those steps right after.

Thank you for any help you may provide :)

Comment: You have a whole lot of options, and only you can decide which one is "best" for your needs and preferences.

Comment: Could you achieve this? I'm trying the same with Cloud Firestore

Comment: Yes, this was quite a while ago, so I don't recall precise details, but in short, this is how I handled it:

Inside my Cloud function called "crudAPIGateway", I created a method called "verifyReceivedRecaptcha" that takes in the body of the recapcha response to validate. I then make a post request to "https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" with my secret. Only if the result is successful, my other methods will then take care of pushing the data to Firebase.